# Ejemplos del Método lastIndexOf() en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, variables, parametros, sintaxis

quisiera que alguien me explique el Método lastIndexOf();No tengo claro el tema. Estoy aprendiendo JavaScript. Agradecería de antemano su ayuda.

Comment: Te invito a que leas [ask], tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede quedar cerrada, mas que solicitar ejemplos ayudaría que indiques que has revisado y que exactamente no entiendes, de esa forma la comunidad sabrá desde que punto ayudarte

Comment: Hola @MEGoDi. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Además, puede consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas aumentar tus posibilidades de obtener ayuda. También, puede consultar [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/lastIndexOf - El método `lastIndexOf()` devuelve el último índice en el que un cierto elemento puede encontrarse en el arreglo, ó -1 si el elemento no se encontrara

Comment: Quizás te pueda ayudar [String.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/lastIndexOf) o [Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/lastIndexOf) de la documentación de Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te indican en los comentarios, cuando tengas estas dudas lo mejor es que vayas a la documentación, ahí te explican lo que hace la función y hay ejemplos.

### `lastIndexOf` en strings

El método [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/lastIndexOf) en cadenas de texto (*strings*) te devuelve el índice de la última ocurrencia del texto que le pases, en la cadena. Si pasas un segundo argumento, indica desde dónde comenzar la búsqueda.

Los ejemplos de abajo son los mismos que en la documentación.

```js
console.log("canal".lastIndexOf("a")); // devuelve 3
console.log("canal".lastIndexOf("a", 2)); // devuelve 1
console.log("canal".lastIndexOf("a", 0)); // devuelve -1
console.log("canal".lastIndexOf("x")); // devuelve -1

// lasIndexOf es sensible a mayúsculas.
console.log("Ballena Azul, Ballena Asesina".lastIndexOf("azul")); // devuelve -1
console.log("Ballena Azul, Ballena Asesina".lastIndexOf("Azul")); // devuelve 8
```

### `lastIndexOf` en arreglos

En [arreglos funciona parecido](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/lastIndexOf), pero con otro tipos de objetos (no solo cadenas de texto).

De nuevo, ejemplos de la documentación:

```js
const animals = ['Dodo', 'Tiger', 'Penguin', 'Dodo'];

console.log(animals.lastIndexOf('Dodo')); // 3
console.log(animals.lastIndexOf('Tiger')); // 1

const array = [2, 5, 9, 2];

console.log(array.lastIndexOf(2)); // 3
console.log(array.lastIndexOf(7)); // -1
console.log(array.lastIndexOf(2, 3)); // 3
console.log(array.lastIndexOf(2, 2)); // 0
console.log(array.lastIndexOf(2, -2)); // 0
console.log(array.lastIndexOf(2, -1)); // 3
```